# Xamarin forms MasterDetailPage Menu icon not shown on iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms project. 
I have MasterDetailPage inside NavigationPage. 
I set icon property of the MasterDetailPage so that icon is supposed to be set as the top left position on the navigation bar. But it does not work.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var masterDetailpage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Icon = "menuIcon.png",
            Master = new Page { Title = "Sample"},
            Detail = new Page()
        };

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(masterDetailpage);
    }
}
```

This never works. If I put NavigationPage as MasterDetailPage's Detail property, and set icon on the Master. It works. 
But it is very important to have MasterDetailPage inside NavigationPage and not vise versa.

Comment: I might be wrong. But Xamarin Docs only show Page Icons for Android versions in Master Detail Pages or do you mean something else? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: By default icon on the iOS is not shown but you can generally add icon on iOS and add it as an icon property of the page. And it works on some cases but not on mine.

Comment: Does the Navigation page maybe somehow override this property setting?

Comment: I have no idea. In the documentation it is explained that navigation page should be set as a Detail page of MasterDetailPage. But I dont want that

Comment: Do you set the Detail page?

Comment: Yes of course, otherwise I will get runtime exception

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to set the `Icon` property of the `Page` being used for the `Master`.

```
 var masterDetailpage = new MasterDetailPage {            
        Master = new Page { Title = "Sample", Icon = "menuIcon.png"},
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page())
    };
```

This assumes you have a png in your iOS project under the Resources folder named `menuIcon.png` that is the hamburger icon you want. You will also need to use a `NavigationPage` around the `Detail` because the `Icon` is shown in the Navigation Bar area.

Comment: thanks but if you read my question at the end I write what you wrote. But this kind of structure works differently, thats why I want to have MasterDetailPage inside NavigationPage and  not the way you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode char can be used to show the "hamburger" menu icon.

You may specify `Title="&#x2630;"` for the master page `ContentPage`-top level tag.

If you use an icon, you may draw a better icon than char. But using Unicode char is simple enough if this is acceptable for you.

It works for iOS and doesn't break Android.

Links:

- [Trigram for heaven (U+2630)](https://graphemica.com/%E2%98%B0)
- [The Unicode character for menu icons ("navicons") ☰](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/the-unicode-character-for-menu-icons).

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the master page in a navigation page, put the icon on the navigation page.

This works for me:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var masterDetailpage = new MasterDetailPage {
            Icon = "menuIcon.png",
            Master = new Page { Title = "Sample"},
            Detail = new Page()
        };

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(masterDetailpage) { Title = "Sample", Icon = "menuIcon.png" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone You can set the title of the menu right before setting your `MainPage` as I have done in the sample code below:

```
var master = new MasterPage();
master.Master.Icon = "my_icon.png";
master.Master.Title = AppResources.Menu; // To get the value from resource files
MainPage = master;
```

`MasterPage` inherits from `MasterDetailsPage` And I was unable to directly set the value from *constructor* of `MasterPage` because of Xamarin's weird errors.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to add to your `AddDelegate` a common fix

```
namespace myApp.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : 
                         global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            // fix for iOS
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            window.RootViewController = App.GetMainPage().CreateViewController();
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

In your PCL project in `App.xaml.cs` you have to add

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = GetMainPage();
}

public static Page GetMainPage()
{
    return new RootPage();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is misleading and does not fix the issue. The code you proposed is redundant for what LoadApplication is doing and the base.FinishedLaunching call.