# MasterDetailPage SlideOut and and Slide In Button not showing in Master detail .To Slide right and slide left out with Button

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

Here is The Code To setting Title and Image butt ..Title Showing button Slider button not Showing

```
  masterPage = new MasterDetailPage()
                    {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                        Master = BuildMenuPage(),
                        Title = AppResources.AppNameWithPortal,
                        IconImageSource =new FileImageSource {File= "slideout.png" }
                    };
```

I have also try  masterPage.IconImageSource ="slideout.png";
still not working[image]

I want this Result

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign icon to master page:
[Xamarin forms MasterDetailPage Menu icon not shown on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326639/xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage-menu-icon-not-shown-on-ios)

```cs
 var masterDetailpage = new MasterDetailPage {            
        Master = new Page { Title = "Sample", Icon = "menuIcon.png"},
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page())
    };
```

Comment: Still not Working

Comment: Whats the bundle action of your image? Check it by right click on image under drawable folder, properties. Make sure its set to Android resource

Comment: Everting in Master detail page is Working Fine Except this ICon

Comment: Are you facing this issue on both the platforms, or only in android?

Comment: Also have you set the masterdetail page as your root page, and not as a navigation page?set it like this: App.Current.MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();

Comment: I have not yet try in IOS Im Justing Testing in Andriod

Comment: I have set like Above you have Mention .Now The Title bar is not showing nor Image icon

Answer (score 0):

I think the screenshot you shared in your question is a screenshot of `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)`. `MasterDetailPage` has different behaviors in different platform. You can check the [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#overview).

If you want the result in the screenshot, you can customize your `masterPage` and add event to the `slideout` button, something like this:

```
<StackLayout>

    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton Source="slideout.png"></ImageButton>
        <Label Text="title">
    </StackLayout>

    <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
        ...
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

The `icon` or `fileImageSoure` you set in the Page will be displayed if supported by the platform under certain circumstances, such as when a `NavigationPage` is displaying a `ContentPage`.

Usually, detailPage has a NavigationPage and the icon and title will be displayed there in Android.

You can check the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-masterdetailpage/) to see the default behavior of MasterDetailPage in Android.

Comment: Im Making in andriod but making programtically not using xamarin the slideout button is not working.

Comment: You mean you are working on a Xamarin.Android project?

Comment: Xamarin.forms Cross plate form  and working for Andriod

Comment: Working in Xamarin.forms not in xamarin.andriod Native

Comment: @zubairz What do you mean by making programtically not using xamarin the slideout button is not working? You can change the IsPresented  property to control whether the master or detail page is presented.

Comment: the problem is that ...Master detail page every thing working right slide left and right also working.the problem is that the slide in and slide out button not showing so that i can slide in or out with button

Comment: @zubairz Can you please provide me a sample project which can reproduce this problem?